# Definition of divergence of a matrix valued function defined over matrices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator

I am trying to figure out the right notion of divergence for matrix valued functions defined on matrices.

Suppose I have $f:\mathbb R^{m\times n}\to\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ defined elementwise by $(f(X))_{ij} = X_{ij}^2$ for $X=(X_{ij})_{i\leq m, j\leq n}$.

So really, $f$ is elementwise squaring. I want to understand what $div(f)$ is, if at all there is a proper notion of this.

I know the definition when $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$, as in that case, $div(f) =\sum_{i=1}^m \partial f_i(x)/\partial x_i$. But when the input and output are matrices, do we just vectorize them and apply the definition of $div$? That doesn't seem right as it seemingly destroys the matrix structure.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can apply $\text{div}$ on each row and get the vector output $(\text{div}f(X)_{i, \cdot})_{i = 1}^m$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Tensor_field

Comment: See this is where I am getting confused. I know this section in the wikipedia article, but it also seems that in a published well-cited paper, the divergence is a scalar.

Comment: How does the paper define divergence for matrix valued functions?

Comment: Simply as $\sum_{i,j}\partial f_{ij}(X)/\partial X_{ij}$. Here $f_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)'$th coordinate function of $f$.

Comment: Then the paper's generalization of divergence seems different from the usual convention. Perhaps link the paper in the question.

Comment: Divergence in the usual setting is not independent of coordinate system, so I don’t know what “destroys the matrix structure” is supposed to mean.